# How to write if statment if at least in one row is number "1"?

Tags: mysql

I have table with rows math, english, P.E. ...
How could I write if statment if atleast one row contains number "1" in it?

Comment: Visit http://www.MySQL.com oh and Google/SO too.

Comment: **Clue:** `SELECT` --- `FROM` --- `WHERE` that should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall translate the comment of fred-ii into SQL words:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (math=1 OR english=1);
```

Is this what you want ?